# Drop down List of Values, selected from result set to use as filter in Ruby in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a search results form which returns a list of @documents of class Document.  A Document has a one Type.  A Type has many Documents.

I have a drop down list filter on the search results to enable the @document list to be filtered based on the type, but at the moment, the list contains all the possible Types.  I only want the Type to appear in the drop down if there is at least one Document within the list of that type.

(There is a second drop down for Status, same problem applies)

This is what I have so far, but it's returning all types.

```
<%= form_for :document_filter, :url => search_results_home_index_path, :html => {:class=>"form-inline"} do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_select :document_type_id , DocumentType.alphabetically , :id,:name,{:prompt=>"Select document type"} %>
  <%= f.collection_select :document_status , Status.for_filter , :id,:name,{:prompt=>"Select document status"}  %>
  <%= f.submit "Go" %>
<%end%>
```

Does Rails have an easy way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a scope for document types that contain documents, something like this (in models/document_type.rb):

```
scope :has_documents, lambda{
  joins(:documents).
  group("document_types.id")
}
```

Then in your collection_select, use the scope:

```
  <%= f.collection_select :document_type_id , DocumentType.has_documents.alphabetically , :id,:name,{:prompt=>"Select document type"} %>
```

(haven't tried this, so not 100% sure it will work as is by the way)

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Won't this apply to all DocumentTypes that have documents within the entire collection, as opposed to the DocumentTypes that have documents in the search results (@documents)?

Comment: It will indeed, sorry should have realised that was a filtered list you were searching on. What are you filtering on, one or multiple fields?

Comment: Multiple, so the user could filter on either Type or Status or Both

Comment: Okay, you're probably better off generating these dropdowns based off the collection. How about something like: `<%= f.collection_select :document_type_id , @documents.document_types.uniq{|t| t.id }.alphabetically , :id,:name,{:prompt=>"Select document type"} %>` Since that's getting all a bit wordy, you'd probably want to factor out to a class method.

Comment: Hmm. Now getting a Will Paginate error.  `undefined method `document_types' for #<WillPaginate::Collection:0x0000000688c6f0>`.  I have to say, Rails totally baffles me...

Comment: `document_types` was a guess on the association name, what do you have in document.rb for the belongs_to association?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16131/discussion-between-cheeseweasel-and-christian-mayne)